# How to display <div> before H1 Title

Tags: hooks, single

I need display custom  block before H1 Title in my posts.

Please, tell me. Is there any function or hook to implement this?

I cant edit file single.php, because I create different single templates (single-portfolio.php, single-post.php etc.).

Comment: I think you can add your custom block in **single-portfolio.php** so why you need function or hook for this ?

Comment: I need it for display a <div> block in all single templates. Is there any function or hook for this?

Comment: Whe you say "before H1 title" do you mean like this: `<div></div><h1>Title</h1>` or do you mean like this: `<h1><div></div>Title</h1>`?

Comment: I mean first variant, this: <div></div><h1>Title</h1>.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use filter like

```
add_filter('the_title', 'new_title', 10, 2);
function new_title($title, $id) {
    if('your-post-type' == get_post_type($id))
        $title = 'Add your DIV block here';
        $title .= $title;
    return $title;
}
```